# How to connect With CPanel MySql DB from localmachine

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, cpanel

I am trying to test the connection from NetBeans IDE8.0 with New Connection Wizard to the Cpanel MySql Database .
I already added my machine ip address in the Remote MySql option of Cpanel but still i am not able to connect with database.
I am getting below error message

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql:// someIP:3306/hariom?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
```

Comment: Sometimes the port needs to be opened in WHM do  you have access to WHM on your server?

Comment: Yes dear i got the package where i can remotely access db

Answer (score 0):

If your server has ConfigServerFirewall installed you need to open the port there as well event though you turned on remote mysql on your cPanel. If you do not own the server you need to contact the host for this.